# Transform a Counter object into a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I used `Counter` on a list to compute this variable:

```
final = Counter(event_container)
```

print final gives:

```
Counter({'fb_view_listing': 76, 'fb_homescreen': 63, 'rt_view_listing': 50, 'rt_home_start_app': 46, 'fb_view_wishlist': 39, 'fb_view_product': 37, 'fb_search': 29, 'rt_view_product': 23, 'fb_view_cart': 22, 'rt_search': 12, 'rt_view_cart': 12, 'add_to_cart': 2, 'create_campaign': 1, 'fb_connect': 1, 'sale': 1, 'guest_sale': 1, 'remove_from_cart': 1, 'rt_transaction_confirmation': 1, 'login': 1})
```

Now I want to convert `final` into a Pandas `DataFrame`, but when I'm doing:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final)
```

but I got an error.

I guess final is not a proper dictionary, so how can I convert `final` to a dictionary? Or is it an other way to convert `final` to a `DataFrame`?

Comment: What do you want the final df to look like? Do you want each entry to be a column or a row?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can construct using [`from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) and pass param `orient='index'`, then call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) so you get a 2 column df:

```
In [40]:
from collections import Counter
d = Counter({'fb_view_listing': 76, 'fb_homescreen': 63, 'rt_view_listing': 50, 'rt_home_start_app': 46, 'fb_view_wishlist': 39, 'fb_view_product': 37, 'fb_search': 29, 'rt_view_product': 23, 'fb_view_cart': 22, 'rt_search': 12, 'rt_view_cart': 12, 'add_to_cart': 2, 'create_campaign': 1, 'fb_connect': 1, 'sale': 1, 'guest_sale': 1, 'remove_from_cart': 1, 'rt_transaction_confirmation': 1, 'login': 1})
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()
df

Out[40]:
                          index   0
0                         login   1
1   rt_transaction_confirmation   1
2                  fb_view_cart  22
3                    fb_connect   1
4               rt_view_product  23
5                     fb_search  29
6                          sale   1
7               fb_view_listing  76
8                   add_to_cart   2
9                  rt_view_cart  12
10                fb_homescreen  63
11              fb_view_product  37
12            rt_home_start_app  46
13             fb_view_wishlist  39
14              create_campaign   1
15                    rt_search  12
16                   guest_sale   1
17             remove_from_cart   1
18              rt_view_listing  50
```

You can rename the columns to something more meaningful:

```
In [43]:
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'event', 0:'count'})
df

Out[43]:
                          event  count
0                         login      1
1   rt_transaction_confirmation      1
2                  fb_view_cart     22
3                    fb_connect      1
4               rt_view_product     23
5                     fb_search     29
6                          sale      1
7               fb_view_listing     76
8                   add_to_cart      2
9                  rt_view_cart     12
10                fb_homescreen     63
11              fb_view_product     37
12            rt_home_start_app     46
13             fb_view_wishlist     39
14              create_campaign      1
15                    rt_search     12
16                   guest_sale      1
17             remove_from_cart      1
18              rt_view_listing     50
```

Comment: Thank you!   Why do you need to pass the param orient='index'?
It certainly works, and thank you for your answer, but in trying to educate myself I don't understand why this param is necessary.

Comment: @HeatherClaxton if you didn't pass `orient='index'` then it will raise a `ValueError` because it then expects you to pass an index, you should experiment with the params to understand the difference in output

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to use `DataFrame.from_records` method

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

c = Counter({'fb_view_listing': 76, 'fb_homescreen': 63, 'rt_view_listing': 50, 'rt_home_start_app': 46, 'fb_view_wishlist': 39, 'fb_view_product': 37, 'fb_search': 29, 'rt_view_product': 23, 'fb_view_cart': 22, 'rt_search': 12, 'rt_view_cart': 12, 'add_to_cart': 2, 'create_campaign': 1, 'fb_connect': 1, 'sale': 1, 'guest_sale': 1, 'remove_from_cart': 1, 'rt_transaction_confirmation': 1, 'login': 1})

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(dict(c).items()), columns=['page','count'])
```

It's a one-liner and speed seems to be the same.

Or use this variant to have them sorted by most used. Again the performance is about the same.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(c.most_common(), columns=['page','count'])
```

Comment: I nominate this as best answer because it you don't need to rename columns afterwards, and it avoids having a data column that is treated as an index rather than an indexed column (due to the "orient" argument in from_dict)

Comment: +1 this solution has lower runtime than the accepted answer. I used `%%time` in `jupyter-notebook` to find the runtime. This one has runtime in `microsecond` range, whereas the accepted answer has two operations and the runtime is in `millisecond` range for `30` entries.

Answer (score 6):

If you want two columns, set the keyword argument `orient='index'` when creating a `DataFrame` from a dictionary using `from_dict`:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final, orient='index')
```

See the [documentation on DataFrame.from_dict](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

Comment: thanks, but this give me a 1 ligne, n column dataframe. How can I have a n lines, 2 columns dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I found it more useful to transform the Counter to a pandas Series that is already ordered by count and where the ordered items are the index, so I used `zip`:

```
def counter_to_series(counter):
  if not counter:
    return pd.Series() 
  counter_as_tuples = counter.most_common(len(counter)) 

  items, counts = zip(*counter_as_tuples)
  return pd.Series(counts, index=items)
```

The `most_common` method of the counter object returns a list of `(item, count)` tuples. `zip` will throw an exception when the counter has no items, so an empty Counter must be checked beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got was probably "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index."
To fix this, just provide an index (e.g., "count") and then transpose:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final, index=['count']).transpose()
```

Done.
You can rename the index afterwards if you wish.