# Difference between Python's collections.Counter and nltk.probability.FreqDist

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to calculate the term-frequencies of words in a text corpus. I've been using NLTK's word_tokenize followed by probability.FreqDist for some time to get this done. The word_tokenize returns a list, which is converted to a frequency distribution by FreqDist. However, I recently came across the Counter function in collections (collections.Counter), which seems to be doing the exact same thing. Both FreqDist and Counter have a most_common(n) function which return the n most common words. Does anyone know if there's a difference between these two? Is one faster than the other? Are there cases where one would work and the other wouldn't?

Comment: You could test the speed on a large corpus(?) Using ```timeit```. ```collections.counter``` will only give you the total count for each word, not a frequency distribution. Play around with it and see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`nltk.probability.FreqDist` is a subclass of `collections.Counter`.

From the [docs](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L61):

> A frequency distribution for the outcomes of an experiment.  A
>   frequency distribution records the number of times each outcome of an
>   experiment has occurred.  For example, a frequency distribution could
>   be used to record the frequency of each word type in a document. 
>   Formally, a frequency distribution can be defined as a function
>   mapping from each sample to the number of times that sample occurred
>   as an outcome.

[The inheritance is explicitly shown from the code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L61) and essentially, there's no difference in terms of how a `Counter` and `FreqDist` is initialized, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L106

So speed-wise, creating a `Counter` and `FreqDist` should be the same. The difference in speed should be insignificant but it's good to note that the overheads could be:

- the compilation of the class in when defining it in an interpreter
- the cost of duck-typing `.__init__()`

The major difference is the various functions that `FreqDist` provides for statistical / probabilistic Natural Language Processing (NLP), e.g. [finding hapaxes](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py#L130). The full list of functions that `FreqDist` extends `Counter` are as followed:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from nltk import FreqDist
>>> x = FreqDist()
>>> y = Counter()
>>> set(dir(x)).difference(set(dir(y)))
set(['plot', 'hapaxes', '_cumulative_frequencies', 'r_Nr', 'pprint', 'N', 'unicode_repr', 'B', 'tabulate', 'pformat', 'max', 'Nr', 'freq', '__unicode__'])
```

When it comes to using `FreqDist.most_common()`, it's actually using the parent function from `Counter` so the speed of retrieving the sorted `most_common` list is the same for both types.

Personally, when I just want to retrieve counts, I use `collections.Counter`. But when I need to do some statistical manipulation, I either use `nltk.FreqDist` or I would dump the `Counter` into a `pandas.DataFrame` (see [Transform a Counter object into a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111032/transform-a-counter-object-into-a-pandas-dataframe)).