# Counting word frequency and writing in an output file

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

From file_test.txt I need to count how many times each word appeared int the file using nltk.FreqDist() function. When I count word frequency I need to see if that word is in pos_dict.txt, and if it is, then multiply the number of word freq with the number standing by the same word in pos_dict.txt.

`file_test.txt` looks like this:

```
  abandon, abandon, calm, clear
```

`pos_dict.txt` looks like this for these words:

```
"abandon":2,"calm":2,"clear":1,...
```

My code is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import nltk

f_input_pos=open('file_test.txt','r').read()

def features_pos(dat):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(dat)
    fdist=nltk.FreqDist(tokens)

    f_pos_dict=open('pos_dict.txt','r').read()
    f=f_pos_dict.split(',') 

    for part in f:
        b=part.split(':')
        c=b[-1]   #to catch the number
        T2 = eval(str(c).replace("'","")) # convert number from string to int

        for word in fdist:
            if word in f_pos_dict:
               d=fdist[word]
               print(word,'->',d*T2)


features_pos(f_input_pos)
```

So my output needs to be like this:

```
abandon->4
calm->2
clear->1
```

But my output is duplicating all outputs and obvioulsy multiplying wrong. I'm a bit stuck and I don't know where is the error, probably I'm using for loops wrong. If somebody can help, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: How does your input file look like? Can you post a link or a sample of the `file_test.txt` and `pos_dict.txt`?

Comment: My input file `file_test.txt` looks the same as I wrote in my question, in `pos_dict.txt` other words are included but are not important for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

First, here's a quick way to read your `pos_dict.txt` file by reading it as a string representation of a dictionary:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ echo '"abandon":2,"calm":2,"clear":1' > pos_dict.txt
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import io
>>> with io.open('pos_dict.txt', 'r') as fin:
...     pos_dict = eval("{" + fin.read() + "}")
... 
>>>
>>> pos_dict['abandon']
2
>>> pos_dict['clear']
1
```

Next, to read your `file_test.txt`, we have to read the file, strip the heading and trailing spaces then split the words up by `,` (comma followed by a space).

Then using the `collections.Counter` object we can get the token counts easily (also see [Difference between Python's collections.Counter and nltk.probability.FreqDist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603922/difference-between-pythons-collections-counter-and-nltk-probability-freqdist)):

```
alvas@ubi:~$ echo 'abandon, abandon, calm, clear' > file_test.txt
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import io
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> with io.open('file_test.txt', 'r') as fin:
...     tokens = fin.read().strip().split(', ')
... 
>>> Counter(tokens)
Counter({u'abandon': 2, u'clear': 1, u'calm': 1})
```

To access the token counts from `file_test.txt` and multiply them with the values of the `pos_dict.txt`, we iterate through the Counter object using the `.items()` function (like how we can access a dictionary's key-value pairs):

```
>>> import io
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> with io.open('file_test.txt', 'r') as fin:
...     tokens = fin.read().strip().split(', ')
... 
>>> 
>>> word_counts = Counter(tokens)
>>> with io.open('pos_dict.txt', 'r') as fin:
...     pos_dict = eval("{" + fin.read() + "}")
... 
>>>
>>> token_times_posdict = {word:freq*pos_dict[word] for word, freq in Counter(tokens).items()}
>>> token_times_posdict
{u'abandon': 4, u'clear': 1, u'calm': 2}
```

And then to print them out:

```
>>> for word, value in token_times_posdict.items():
...     print "{} -> {}".format(word, value)
... 
abandon -> 4
clear -> 1
calm -> 2
```

Comment: I guess i have resolved your "homework" but please do understand the code and not just copy and paste them.

Comment: BTW, also the `dict.items()` function would not sort the keys by its value, try looking at `Counter`'s function and you'll find that there's one function to do just what you'll be looking for (Hint: `from collections import Counter; dir(Counter)` =)

Comment: Thank you for you effort, It is really a good solution. I understand the code. Since I'm new in  language processing and nltk I didn't know about representing  strings as dictionary, but now it's clear.  Thank you

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped. Have fun with Python and NLTK =)

Comment: Maybe this would help you a little when it comes to understanding Python's container: https://github.com/usaarhat/pywarmups/blob/master/session2.md