# Sorting FreqDist in NLTK with get vs get()

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nlp, nltk

I am playing around with NLTK and the module freqDist

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
print(gutenberg.fileids())
from nltk import FreqDist
fd = FreqDist()

for word in gutenberg.words('austen-persuasion.txt'):
    fd[word] += 1

newfd = sorted(fd, key=fd.get, reverse=True)[:10]
```

So I am playing around with NLTK and have a question regarding the sort portion. When I run the code like this it properly sorts the freqDist object. However when I run it with get() instead of get I encounter the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\NLP\NLP.py", line 21, in <module>
newfd = sorted(fd, key=fd.get(), reverse=True)[:10]
TypeError: get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

Why is get right and get() wrong. I was under the impression that get() should be correct, but I guess it is not.

Comment: Most probably what you need is `fd.most_common()`. Essentially, FreqDist in NLTK is a collections.Counter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603922/difference-between-pythons-collections-counter-and-nltk-probability-freqdist/34606637#34606637

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, the `FreqDist` object in `NLTK` is a sub-class of the native Python's `collections.Counter`, so let's see how `Counter` works:

A `Counter` is a dictionary which stores the elements in a list as its key and the counts of the elements as the values:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(['a','a','b','c','c','c','d'])
Counter({'c': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
>>> c = Counter(['a','a','b','c','c','c','d'])
```

To get a list of elements sorted by their frequency, you can use `.most_common()` function and it will return a tuple of the element and its count sorted by the counts.

```
>>> c.most_common()
[('c', 3), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

And in reverse:

```
>>> list(reversed(c.most_common()))
[('d', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Like a dictionary you can iterate through a Counter object and it will return the keys:

```
>>> [key for key in c]
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
>>> c.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```

You can also use the `.items()` function to get a tuple of the keys and their values:

```
>>> c.items()
[('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('b', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

Alternatively, if you only need the keys sorted by their counts, see [Transpose/Unzip Function (inverse of zip)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339/a-transpose-unzip-function-in-python-inverse-of-zip):

```
>>> k, v = zip(*c.most_common())
>>> k
('c', 'a', 'b', 'd')
```

Going back to the question of `.get` vs `.get()`, the former is the function itself, while the latter is an instance of the function that requires the key of the dictionary as its parameter:

```
>>> c = Counter(['a','a','b','c','c','c','d'])
>>> c
Counter({'c': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
>>> c.get
<built-in method get of Counter object at 0x7f5f95534868>
>>> c.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
>>> c.get('a')
2
```

When invoking the `sorted()`, the `key=...` parameter inside the `sorted` function is **not** the key of the list/dictionary you're sorting but the key that `sorted` should use for sorting.

So these are the same, but they only return the values of the keys:

```
>>> [c.get(key) for key in c]
[2, 3, 1, 1]
>>> [c[key] for key in c]
[2, 3, 1, 1]
```

And when sorting, the values are used as the criteria for sorting, so these achieves the same output:

```
>>> sorted(c, key=c.get)
['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']
>>> v, k = zip(*sorted((c.get(key), key) for key in c))
>>> list(k)
['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']
>>> sorted(c, key=c.get, reverse=True) # Highest to lowest
['c', 'a', 'b', 'd']
>>> v, k = zip(*reversed(sorted((c.get(key), key) for key in c)))
>>> k
('c', 'a', 'd', 'b')
```

Comment: Very Nice Explanation !!.  The  "c.most_common( )" method above is my favorite, it goes directly to the point. Note : this is already assumed, but if some people skip it,  you still have to loop first as shown in the question above, than print out the "c.most_common( )"