# plot the 50 least frequent words with nltk

Tags: python, plot, nlp, nltk

How do I plot the 50 least frequent words?

Maybe I am thinking too complicated. Here's the way I get the words:

```
distr = nltk.FreqDist(word for word in items)
words = distr .keys()
seldomwords = words [:50]
```

How do I plot this now?

With the `plot` function of `FreqDist` I get all or only the x most frequent words.

I tried something like:

```
distr .plot(:50)
```

But that's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427673/sorting-freqdist-in-nltk-with-get-vs-get/37429443#37429443

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's sort of strange but the simplest way is to

- first you have to extract the least common items from the `FreqDist`
- then recreate the least common items and feed it back into a new FreqDist object
- use `FreqDist.plot()` using the new FreqDist.

[Code]:

```
>>> from nltk import FreqDist
>>> fd = FreqDist(list('aaabbbbbcccccdddddddd'))
>>> last_two = FreqDist(dict(fd.most_common()[-2:]))
>>> last_two.plot()
```

[out]:

[image]

[Code]:

```
>>> from nltk import FreqDist
>>> fd = FreqDist(list('aaabbbbbcccccdddddddd'))
>>> last_two = FreqDist(dict(fd.most_common()[-2:]))
>>> last_two.plot()
>>> last_three = FreqDist(dict(fd.most_common()[-3:]))
>>> last_three.plot()
```

[out]:

[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!