# How to remove List special characters ("()", "'",",") from the output of a bi / tri-gram in Python

Tags: python, nltk, special-characters

I have written a code that calculates bigram / trigram frequency from a text input, using NLTK. The problem that I am facing here is that since the output is obtained in form of a Python List, my output contains list specific characters i.e. ("()", "'",","). I plan to export this into a csv file, and thus I would want to remove these special characters at the code level itself. How can I make that edit.

Input Code:

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
from nltk.collocations import *
from itertools import *
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

corpus = '''The pure amnesia of her face,
newborn. I looked so far into her that, for a while, looked so far into her that, for a while  looked so far into her that, for a while looked so far into her that, for a while the visual 
held no memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse the visual held no  memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse
'''
s_corpus = corpus.lower()

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s_corpus)
tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in stop_words]

c_tokens = [''.join(e for e in string if e.isalnum()) for string in tokens]
c_tokens = [x for x in c_tokens if x]

bgs_2 = nltk.bigrams(c_tokens)
bgs_3 = nltk.trigrams(c_tokens)

fdist = nltk.FreqDist(bgs_3)

tmp = list()
for k,v in fdist.items():
    tmp.append((v,k))
tmp = sorted (tmp, reverse=True)

for kk,vv in tmp[:]:
    print (vv,kk)
```

Current Output:

```
('looked', 'far', 'looked') 3
('far', 'looked', 'far') 3
('visual', 'held', 'memory') 2
('returned', 'waking', 'nurse') 2
```

Expected Output:

```
looked far looked, 3
far looked far, 3
visual held memory, 2
returned waking nurse, 2
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Those special characters are not actually part of the list. They are just formatted that way when you use the `print()` command. The values contained in the list are just the words you want (no `(` or `,` or `'` in them)

Comment: " I plan to export this into a csv file," - just do that and it'll be fine

Comment: Even I had exported them into a CSV format, the special characters still remained & I had to remove them manually in Excel; any way to avoid having them ?

Comment: @AyushSaxena if that is the case you should show how you are exporting the values to CSV or create a question related to that because the error is probably occuring in the way you are saving it to the CSV file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better question would have been **what are those `("()", "'",",")` in the ngrams output?**

```
>>> from nltk import ngrams
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize

# Split a sentence into a list of "words"
>>> word_tokenize("This is a foo bar sentence")
['This', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar', 'sentence']
>>> type(word_tokenize("This is a foo bar sentence"))
<class 'list'>

# Extract bigrams.
>>> list(ngrams(word_tokenize("This is a foo bar sentence"), 2))
[('This', 'is'), ('is', 'a'), ('a', 'foo'), ('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'sentence')]

# Okay, so the output is a list, no surprise.
>>> type(list(ngrams(word_tokenize("This is a foo bar sentence"), 2)))
<class 'list'>
```

But what type is `('This', 'is')`?

```
>>> list(ngrams(word_tokenize("This is a foo bar sentence"), 2))[0]
('This', 'is')
>>> first_thing_in_output = list(ngrams(word_tokenize("This is a foo bar sentence"), 2))[0]
>>> type(first_thing_in_output)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Ah, it's a tuple, see https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/

**What happens when you print a tuple?**

```
>>> print(first_thing_in_output)
('This', 'is')
```

**What happens if you convert them into a `str()`?**

```
>>> print(str(first_thing_in_output))
('This', 'is')
```

But **I want the output `This is`** instead of `('This', 'is')`, so I will use the `str.join()` function, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/:

```
>>> print(' '.join((first_thing_in_output)))
This is
```

Now this is a good point to really go through [the tutorial of basic Python types](https://realpython.com/python-data-types/) to understand what is happening. Additionally, it'll be good to understand how "container" types work too, e.g. https://github.com/usaarhat/pywarmups/blob/master/session2.md

---

Going through the original post, there are quite some issues with the code.

I guess the goal of the code is to:

- Tokenize the text and remove stopwords
- Extract ngrams (without stopwords)
- Print out their string forms and their counts

The tricky part is the `stopwords.words('english')` does not contain punctuation, so you'll end up with strange ngrams that contains punctuations:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

text = '''The pure amnesia of her face,
newborn. I looked so far into her that, for a while, looked so far into her that, for a while  looked so far into her that, for a while looked so far into her that, for a while the visual 
held no memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse the visual held no  memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse
'''

stoplist = set(stopwords.words('english'))

tokens = [token for token in nltk.word_tokenize(text) if token not in stoplist]

list(ngrams(tokens, 2))
```

[out]:

```
[('The', 'pure'),
 ('pure', 'amnesia'),
 ('amnesia', 'face'),
 ('face', ','),
 (',', 'newborn'),
 ('newborn', '.'),
 ('.', 'I'),
 ('I', 'looked'),
 ('looked', 'far'),
 ('far', ','),
 (',', ','), ...]
```

Perhaps you would like to extend the stoplist with punctuations, e.g.

```
from string import punctuation
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

text = '''The pure amnesia of her face,
newborn. I looked so far into her that, for a while, looked so far into her that, for a while  looked so far into her that, for a while looked so far into her that, for a while the visual 
held no memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse the visual held no  memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse
'''

stoplist = set(stopwords.words('english') + list(punctuation))

tokens = [token for token in nltk.word_tokenize(text) if token not in stoplist]

list(ngrams(tokens, 2))
```

[out]:

```
[('The', 'pure'),
 ('pure', 'amnesia'),
 ('amnesia', 'face'),
 ('face', 'newborn'),
 ('newborn', 'I'),
 ('I', 'looked'),
 ('looked', 'far'),
 ('far', 'looked'),
 ('looked', 'far'), ...]
```

Then you realized that tokens like `I` should be a stopword but still exists in your list of ngrams. It's because the list from `stopwords.words('english')` are lowercased, e.g.

```
>>> stopwords.words('english')
```

[out]:

```
['i',
 'me',
 'my',
 'myself',
 'we',
 'our',
 'ours',
 'ourselves',
 'you',
 "you're", ...]
```

So when you're checking whether a token is in the stoplist, you should also lowercase the token. (**Avoid** lowercasing the sentence before `word_tokenize` because `word_tokenize` may take cues from capitalization). Thus:

```
from string import punctuation
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

text = '''The pure amnesia of her face,
newborn. I looked so far into her that, for a while, looked so far into her that, for a while  looked so far into her that, for a while looked so far into her that, for a while the visual 
held no memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse the visual held no  memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse
'''

stoplist = set(stopwords.words('english') + list(punctuation))

tokens = [token for token in nltk.word_tokenize(text) if token.lower() not in stoplist]

list(ngrams(tokens, 2))
```

[out]:

```
[('pure', 'amnesia'),
 ('amnesia', 'face'),
 ('face', 'newborn'),
 ('newborn', 'looked'),
 ('looked', 'far'),
 ('far', 'looked'),
 ('looked', 'far'),
 ('far', 'looked'),
 ('looked', 'far'),
 ('far', 'looked'), ...]
```

Now the ngrams looks like it's achieving the objectives:

- Tokenize the text and remove stopwords
- Extract ngrams (without stopwords)

---

Then on the last part where you want to print out the ngrams to a file in sorted order, you could actually use the `Freqdist.most_common()` which will list in descending order, e.g.

```
from string import punctuation
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import FreqDist

text = '''The pure amnesia of her face,
newborn. I looked so far into her that, for a while, looked so far into her that, for a while  looked so far into her that, for a while looked so far into her that, for a while the visual 
held no memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse the visual held no  memory. Little by little, I returned to myself, waking to nurse
'''

stoplist = set(stopwords.words('english') + list(punctuation))

tokens = [token for token in nltk.word_tokenize(text) if token.lower() not in stoplist]

FreqDist(ngrams(tokens, 2)).most_common()
```

[out]:

```
[(('looked', 'far'), 4),
 (('far', 'looked'), 3),
 (('visual', 'held'), 2),
 (('held', 'memory'), 2),
 (('memory', 'Little'), 2),
 (('Little', 'little'), 2),
 (('little', 'returned'), 2),
 (('returned', 'waking'), 2),
 (('waking', 'nurse'), 2),
 (('pure', 'amnesia'), 1),
 (('amnesia', 'face'), 1),
 (('face', 'newborn'), 1),
 (('newborn', 'looked'), 1),
 (('far', 'visual'), 1),
 (('nurse', 'visual'), 1)]
```

(See also: [Difference between Python's collections.Counter and nltk.probability.FreqDist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603922/difference-between-pythons-collections-counter-and-nltk-probability-freqdist))

Final finally, printing it out to file, you should really use a context manager, http://eigenhombre.com/introduction-to-context-managers-in-python.html

```
with open('bigrams-list.tsv', 'w') as fout:
    for bg, count in FreqDist(ngrams(tokens, 2)).most_common():
        print('\t'.join([' '.join(bg), str(count)]), end='\n', file=fout)
```

[bigrams-list.tsv]:

```
looked far  4
far looked  3
visual held 2
held memory 2
memory Little   2
Little little   2
little returned 2
returned waking 2
waking nurse    2
pure amnesia    1
amnesia face    1
face newborn    1
newborn looked  1
far visual  1
nurse visual    1
```

---

## Food for thought

Now you see this strange bigram `Little little`, **does it make sense?**

It's a by-product of removing `by` from

> Little by little

So now, depending on what's the ultimate task for the ngrams you've extracted, you might not really want to remove stopwords from the list.

Comment: Excellent response ! Lot of my questions that I had in my mind got cleared with this one detailed response. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So just to "fix" your output:
Use this to print your data:

```
for kk,vv in tmp:
    print(" ".join(list(kk)),",%d" % vv)
```

**BUT** if you are going to parse this into an csv you should collect your output in a different format.

Currently you are creating a list of tupels containing a tupel and a number.
try to collect your data as a list of lists containing each value.
That way you can just write it directly into an csv file.

Take a look here: [Create a .csv file with values from a Python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084069/create-a-csv-file-with-values-from-a-python-list)